# How to add a keyboard function to calculator label tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Ive finished a basic calculator in tkinter python, and all that's left to do now is allow the user to use the keyboard in the calculator as well. I've tried using the config function but that ends up just replacing all of the text in the label, as usual. This is the code for the calculator so far.

```
from tkinter import *
e = Tk(className="Krishna's Calculator")
e.geometry("460x614")
e.resizable(bool(0),bool(0))
def insert(value):
    var.set(var.get() + value)
    eval(var.get())
def button(text, width, font, highlightbackground, x, y):
    tkinter_button = Button(e, text=text, width=width, command=lambda: insert(text), font=font, highlightbackground=highlightbackground)
    tkinter_button.place(x=x, y=y)
def clear():
    var.set(" ") 
def equals(vare):
    var.set(eval(vare))
for sym in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'):
    def Button1(text, x, y):
        Tkinterbutton = Button(e, text = text, width = 4, command=lambda: insert(text), font = arial, highlightbackground=white)
        Tkinterbutton.place(x=x, y=y)
helvetica = "Helvetica 50"   
arial = "Arial 50 bold"
purple = '#8533ff'
white = '#ffffff'
grey = '#737373'
var = StringVar()
label = Label(e, textvariable = var,bd=5,width=16, relief = SOLID, font = "Arial 50 ",bg="white", fg="black",activebackground="#bb99ff", height = 5,pady = 3)
label.place(x=0,y=0)
button(text = "-", width=4, font = helvetica, highlightbackground=purple, x = 344, y = 426)
button(text = "+", width=4, font = helvetica, highlightbackground=purple, x = 344, y = 488)
equal = Button(e, text = "=",width=4, command = lambda: equals(var.get()), font = helvetica, highlightbackground=purple)
equal.place(x = 344, y = 551)
aclear = Button(e, text = "AC",width=4, command = clear, font = helvetica ,highlightbackground=grey)
aclear.place(x = 0, y = 302)
square = Button(e, text = "^",width=4, command = lambda: insert("**"), font = helvetica,highlightbackground=grey)
square.place(x = 228, y = 301)
divide = Button(e, text = "÷",width=4, command = lambda: insert("/"), font = helvetica ,highlightbackground=purple)
divide.place(x = 344, y = 301)
multiply = Button(e, text = "x",width=4, command = lambda: insert("*"), font = helvetica ,highlightbackground=purple)
multiply.place(x = 344, y = 364)
delete = Button(e, text = "C",width=4, command=lambda: var.set(var.get()[:-1]), font = helvetica ,highlightbackground=grey)
delete.place(x = 114, y = 302)
Button1(text = ".", x = 228, y = 550)
button(text = "0", width = 8, font = arial, highlightbackground=white,x = 0, y = 550)
Button1(text = "1",  x = 0, y = 488)
Button1(text = "2", x = 114, y = 488)
Button1(text = "3", x = 228, y = 488)
Button1(text = "4", x = 0, y = 426)
Button1(text = "5", x = 114, y = 426)
Button1(text = "6", x = 228, y = 426)
Button1(text = "7", x = 0, y = 364)
Button1(text = "8", x = 114, y = 364)
Button1(text = "9", x = 228, y = 364)
e.mainloop()
```

I'm not sure how to do this without Object Oriented Programming (OOP).
If there's any way to do this without OOP, please let me know. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you very much!

Comment: Please update your question with the code which uses config in response to key presses.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to type the numbers with the buttons on the calculator GUI.
If so just import pyautogui library

```
import pyautogui
```

then create a function which will type the number

```
def num_1():
            pyautogui.write('1')
```

But you can't use your keyboard to type out the numbers as you are not using an entry widget.